# discord.js mandar mensagens privadas programadas para user com uma role

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ola

Nao sei se alguem tem conhecimento de discord.js porem mesmo assim vou perguntar

Estou fazendo um pequeno guia de aluno, ou seja, algo que possa avisar o aluno do que esta acontecendo na sua vida escolar

O que estou tentando fazer nao e mandar mensagens privadas programadas visto que uso node.schedule para tal, mas sim envialas para pessoas com uma role especifica

```
    const botconfig = require('./botconfig.json');
const token = '*';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var classA = '?';
var sumaryA = '?';
var profA = '?';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);



  var class8_30 = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 8, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 1}, function(){
    classA = 'English'; 
    client.users.get("500087456046120961").send("Class now");
  });

});

client.on('message', msg => {

  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
  }

  if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!myclassis')){
    var args = msg.content.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    console.log(args);
    if(args[1] === '10a'){
      var t10A = msg.guild.roles.find('name', 'Class_10A');
      msg.member.addRole(t10A.id);
      msg.channel.send('You\'re now part of class 10A');
    }
  }

  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "class"){
    let c10A = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "Class_10A");
    if (msg.member.roles.has(c10A.id)) 
        msg.author.send(aulaA);
  }

});

client.login(token);
```

A forma que tenho agora e mandar mensagem por id o que e bastante (in)pratico e nao e automatico, ja vi uma quantidade enorme de videos, ja li os docs mas eu nao consigo encontrar em lado nenhum porem acho que existe

Se alguem me pudesse ajudar eu agradecia pela ajuda e pelo tempo gasto com este meu problema :)

Obs: peco desculpas pela falta de acentos, teclado ingles em linux ingles :/
Obs 2: discord.js nao tem reputacao suficiente nas tags por isso coloquei no titulo

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer resgatar todos os usuários de um cargo de um servidor específico, em vez de lançar vários `client.users.get().send()` para cada usuário.
Você pode recuperar esses usuários usando `client.guilds.get().roles.get().members`:

```js
client.guilds.get("ID do servidor").roles.get("ID da role").members.forEach((membro) => {
    membro.user.send("Class now")
})
```